# Sqlmap, update query and risk param

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap, risk

I was reading about the 'risk' param for sqlmap, and the docs contain information, that risk 3 level can update tables. What does it mean? As far as I understand, this can happen either in the app update injection or if the app's logic updates some table.
Am I right? Or it is possible somehow to update tables accidentally even in select query while using sqlmap?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say there's an injection possibility on an action that results in the deletion of a single result.

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE userId=1;
```

A risk level of 1 or 2 is likely to result in a single user being deleted.

Risk level 3 uses `OR` which can end up effecting many more rows than intended.

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE userId=1 OR 1=1;
```

It's not that risk 1 & 2 don't have the possibility of deleting or updating database records, rather their impact is likely limited in scope; while risk 3 is more likely to destroy (or make your presence known by disruption) an application before you can effectively exploit it.

Comment: As usual, the devil is in the detail.. Thank you very much for explanation